# Hanging a pipe - construction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

A contractor wants to pick up a 10-ft diameter pipe with a chain length 40 ft. The chain encircles the pipe and is attached to a hook on the crane. What is the distance between the hook and the pipe?

Any suggested starting points for solving this problem?

Comment: To me the distance might be $0$.

Comment: You must substract to the total length of the chain (40 ft) the length of the part of the chain that encircles the pipe : assuming that the thickness of the chain is infinitely small and that the axe of the pipe is orthogonal of the axe of the chain (that is, the pipe is picked up horizontally), this length is the circumference of the pipe of diameter 10 ft.

Comment: How much of the chain is wrapped around the pipe?

Comment: The chain is perpendicular to the length of the pipe (it is being picked up prefectly centered, gravity-wise), and yes, we are assuming that it is "infinitely small," or in other words, we are measuring only the edge of the chain closest to the pipe (which is the same as the edge that actually touches the hook on the crane).

Comment: Also, the circumference of the pipe is 10$$\pi\, or about 31.416 ft., so that means that the chain is 8.584 ft longer than the circumference of the pipe. Also, since the pipe is hanging perfectly level and since the chain is perfectly plumb, there is a point on both sides of the pipe where the chain is no longer touching...

Our "x" is from the top of the pipe to the bottom of the chain...it seems like we need to figure out where the chord is that is formed by the chain's point of departure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a right-angled triangle where the hypotenuse is the distance from the center of the pipe to the hook, i.e. the hypotenuse has length $r + x$, where $r$ is the radius of the pipe and $x$ is the distance from the pipe to the hook. And the adjacent side has the length $r$.

Then you have

$$\cos \theta = \frac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypotenuse}} = \frac{5}{5+x}$$

Use this $\theta$ to find the angle the chain makes around the pipe and with this angle you can calculate the arc length of the chain around the pipe, i.e. how  much of the chain that is in contact with the pipe.

Once you have this arc length you can calculate the length of the opposite side in the right-angled triangle and go from there.